# Best Practice - Binding Service to an Activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity

I have a network Service which runs in the background. I have this global variable `mConnection` inside the Activity

```
protected ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        serviceobject = ((NetworkService.MyBinder) binder).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        serviceobject = null;
    }
};
```

and then I bind the Service  in the Activity's `onCreate(..)` using

```
bindService(new Intent(this, NetworkService.class), 
                 mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The NetworkService class has an inner class MyBinder

```
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    NetworkService getService() {
        return NetworkService.this;
    }
}
```

Now to invoke any Service method from the Activity, i use the `serviceobject` and I create an `AsyncTask` for each method invocation.(I know that invoking Service methods from the Activity nullifies the use of having Services.I use this for light methods which doesn't involve much computation)

This helps me to directly deal with the data from the `Service` using the `serviceobject` . 
I unbind the Service in the `Activity`'s `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    unbindService(mConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Is this the best way of doing it or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: +1 I am doing similar sort of thing in my project and think this is the best design from OO perspective, the key point here is isolate business logic from UI stuff, much like a classical MVC approach (V for Activity and C for Service), service class is focusing on business logic implementation, where an how to use it (synchronously or asynchronously) is controlled in activity class.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanna do is to run a `Remote Service`. That's what `ServiceConnection` and `bindService` is used to. The idea is that your service runs in the baackground and any activity can "bind" to it and interact through in interface you define in AIDL.

The access to the service is fast so you can call method from your service from the UI thread without the use of`AsyncTask`. That's one benefit.

However the implementation is a bit tedious because you must write this AIDL interface.

I recommend you to read Google's tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

And then to google "Remote Service AIDL" with "tutorial" or "example".

Good Luck.

Comment: I guess i didn't frame the question properly.No I'm not running a `Remote` Service. This Service runs in  the Same Process in which my Activity runs.Thanks for the information.This is something new to me :-)

Comment: The methods you're using are of no use then. You must use other ways to establish communication such as `Broadcasts` or callbacks.

Comment: can you tell me where I'm wrong? I mean I'm trying to implement the standard procedure of communicating between Activity and Service.Other applications doesn't access my Service and so I think AIDL won't be an option for me.

Comment: You can use ServiceConnection and bindService only with remote services and they are related to an AIDL interface. You can use instead a simpler way such a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` which is very easy to implement: your service broadcasts information and your activity listens and implements an `onReceive()` method which contains the code to be executed when a broadcast is received. Is that clearer??

Comment: I think you are wrong there. I'm totally new to Android, but I have gone through lots of documentation on the net to design a proper strategy to bind the local service to an activity.Please have  a look at these links - [android dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) , [ozdroid](http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for pointing me to that. Regarding your question, the connection to the service is fast (at least for remote services) and you can call methods directly from the UI thread. AsyncTask should not be necessary.

Comment: yea you are right but if the method that you are invoking has some network operations which doesn't run on a new thread, then it will throw  a NetworkOnMainThread Exception.